# Output is correct but SPOJ gave me wrong answer

Tags: c++

Quick question. This is the code that I wrote to finish a problem in SPOJ. The output is correct but it gives me wrong answer. Whats wrong with my code? This is the link to the question: https://www.spoj.com/problems/SUMUP/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
 
void cal(int n){
    long double a, b, c;
    a = (n*n) + n;
    b = 2.0 *(n*n + n + 1.0);
    c = a / b;
    cout<< setprecision(5) << c << '\n';
}
 
int main()
{   int n, z, t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    const int NUMS = t;
    int bobo[NUMS];
 
    for(z = 0; z < NUMS; z++){
        scanf("%d", &bobo[n]);
        cal(bobo[n]);
    }
 
 
    return 0;
}
```

This is the input:

```
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

This is my output:

```
0.33333
0.42857
0.46154
0.47619
0.48387
```

Comment: Please copy the problem as text in the post,  not as through a link. What is NA?

Comment: In case you believe that `bobo` is not a variable-length array: note that it is, since the  value of `NUMS` is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the lines:

```
for(z = 0; z < NUMS; z++){
    scanf("%d", &bobo[n]);
    cal(bobo[n]);
}
```

You should use `z` instead of `n` when calling `scanf()` and `cal()`

Comment: Good eyes. :) Not sure what the array is for, the code would be fine without it since the values stored aren't ever used again.

Comment: You can save the number to `n` like this `scanf("%d", &n);` and then pass it to `cal()`

Answer (score 2):

SPOJ expected output seems to require trailing zeroes, which the `setprecision(5)` function removes from c output if there's any. To keep the trailing zeroes you can add `left << setfill('0') << setw(7)` in your `cout` to indicate that there should be at least 7 characters presents in your output line (two characters for '0.' and 5 decimal places) and if there're fewer characters, it will fill to the left side with '0's, adding back the trailing zeroes required.

```
cout << left << setfill('0') << setw(7) << setprecision(5) << c << '\n';
```

Another more elegant solution is to use `printf` instead

```
printf("%.5Lf\n",c);
```

```
void cal(int n){
    long double a, b, c;
    a = (n*n) + n;
    b = 2.0 *(n*n + n + 1.0);
    c = a / b;
    printf("%.5Lf\n",c);
}
```